# Delayed Job Error - DlayedJob is not a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, delayed-job

I am using rails 3.1.3 for my application. For background job delayed job 2.1.4 is using.
Now I am trying to update the delayed job to 3.x.

Installed both delayed_job 3.x and delayed_job_active_record gem.

After bundle install tried to run rails **generate delayed_job:active_record** and **rails generate delayed_job:upgrade**. But both generator command are throwing errors. First throwing

**Could not load generator "generators/delayed_job/active_record_generator". Error: DelayedJob is not a module**

while later throwing

**Could not load generator "generators/delayed_job/upgrade_generator". Error: DelayedJob is not a module**

Can any one please tell a solution and what I did wrong.

Thank you Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is,while upgrading from delayed_jobs older versions to new version the delayed jobs table will be already there. So might be the delayed_bob generator will not be there. The main difference in table structure is an additional column named **queue**. So we need to add this column to delayed_jobs table. The generator command also doing the same job. It generate the migration for alter the table and add the column. I found it by reading the source. So we can manually write a migration to alter the table.

```
    rails g migration migration name
```

Then add below code to migration and run the migration.

```
    def up
      add_column :delayed_jobs, :queue, :string
    end
    def down
      remove_column :delayed_jobs, :queue
    end
```

Now you can work with multiple delayed job and assign jobs based on queues.